# Pandas write Excel escape '='-sign at start of field

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Using Python Pandas, I want to write some content to an Excel file: `=) some text`

How can I do this safely without getting an Excel error? I use the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(["=) some text"])
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("test_file.xlsx")
df.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()
```

This specific text input creates an incorrect Excel file, since it starts with an '=' and an incorrect formula. Is there some way to escape the '='? I tried to escape the entire text field with quotes, which works, but I was wondering whether there exists a more elegant solution. Maybe one can set the column type (like [explained here](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html))?

Comment: use `'` before `=`

Answer (score 0):

In Excel you can add some code before the workbook is saved:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Worksheets(<YourWorksheet>).Cells(row, column).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "@"
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm looking for an answer in Python, so I can solve this issue code-wise. This solution is in Excel I presume? Where should I enter this command?

Comment: sorry, my misunderstanding. I changed my answer to do it in Excel before save the file.

Comment: I'm sorry, this doesn't really answer the question of how to do this in Python

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding `'` at the beginning of your text, Excel will automatically treat that as string:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["'=) some text"])
```

And from the link you provided you can apply the following:

```
format1 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '@'})
worksheet.set_column('A:A', None, format1)
```

Finally you can convert your whole `df` to a Excel-acceptable string:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: "'" + x)
```

Comment: That's what I did, but I was wondering whether there was a more elegant solution

Comment: I get the point of the answer, but the error remains unsolved. The field is still executed as an invalid formula

Comment: How about `df.apply()`?